# How to search elements of a list in a file

Tags: python-2.7

Please check the code for searching list elements in file.

```
f=open("a.txt","r")
p=open("b.txt","r")
disk=[]
for line in p:
    line = line.strip()
    disk.append(line)


for line in f.readlines():
    for word in disk[0]:
        if word in line:
            print line
```

The list is below:

```
>>> disk
['5000cca025884d5', '5000cca025a1ee6']
```

I want to search this list elements in file below, but I am not getting the output for index `0`.

```
c0t5000CCA025A1EE6Cd0 <preSUN30G-A2B0-279.40GB> /scsi_vhci/disk@g5000cca025a1ee6c


1. c0t5000CCA025A28FECd0 <preSUN30G-A2B0-279.40GB> i/disk@g5000cca025a28fec
2. c0t5000CCA0258BA1DCd0 <HsdfdsSUN30G-A2B0 cyl 46873 alt 2 hd 20 sec 625> i/disk@g5000cca0258ba1dc
3. c0t5000CCA025884D5Cd0 <UN300G cyl 46873 alt 2 hd 20 sec 625>  solaris i/disk@g5000cca025884d5c
4. c0t5000CCA02592705Cd0 <UN300G cyl 46873 alt 2 hd 20 sec 625>  solaris i/disk@g5000cca02592705c
```

Comment: What is your question? Are you getting an error? General code reviews are off-topic for Stack Overflow. See [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Thanks a lot i mean the above code is not searching the list elements in file but displaying the completed file

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include an explanation of what you're trying to do and what the problem is? The edit button is directly below the tags.

Comment: Done the editing thanks

Comment: Your problem is the `for word in disk[0]` part. `disk[0]` is grabbing the first element of `disk`, which would be a string. Then your `for` loop is looping through each character. If you remove the `[0]`, it will actually loop through all the words in `disk`.

Comment: i tried with disk removing [0] but it did not print any think.                             Please help in the code.

Comment: Can you give examples of what is in `a.txt` and what is in `b.txt`? As it is written, it's unclear what's in each. I'm guessing that `a.txt` contains the text at the end of your question, but you haven't made that clear, nor shown what is in `b.txt`.

Comment: Please check below the contents of a.txt                                                    disk01
disk02                                                                                                             and contents of b.txt are:                                                                           
  01.  deldisk01 <del-smd-lstpst-stat-sdfdfh>
  02.  deldisk02shu <del-smd-lstpst-stat-sdfdfh>
  03.  deldisk03del <del-smd-lstpst-stat-sdfdfh>

Comment: Any help with this code in python is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The only error that presents itself in your code is this:

```
  for word in disk[0]:
```

As I mentioned in the comments, what this does is grab the first string in the `disk` list and start iterating over the individual characters. This will lead to most of the lines in `a.txt` getting printed multiple times.

Another possible problem would be getting the two files backwards. I did this accidentally when I was trying to duplicate your problem. When the files are backwards, nothing gets printed, because none of the lines in `a.txt` are in `b.txt` (in fact, most of them are much longer).

Here is a [project on repl.it](https://repl.it/JcrA) that shows the program working.